NestJS ObjectId pipe validation don't work if the param type in the controller is ObjectId
I have a pipe in NestJS to verify that a query param is valid ObjectId. It takes a string as input and returns an ObjectId.
// parse-objectid.pipe.ts
import type { PipeTransform } from '@nestjs/common'
import { Injectable, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common'
import { Types } from 'mongoose'

@Injectable()
export class ParseObjectIdPipe implements PipeTransform<string, Types.ObjectId> {
  public transform(value: string): Types.ObjectId {
    if (!Types.ObjectId.isValid(value)) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Validation failed (ObjectId is expected)')
    }
    return new Types.ObjectId(value)
  }
}

The problem is that when I use the pipe in the controller and set the param type to ObjectId, it gives an error
// book.controller.ts
@Get('books')
async getBooks(@Query('author_id', ParseObjectIdPipe) authorId: Types.ObjectId){}

{
    "message": [
        "an unknown value was passed to the validate function"
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "statusCode": 400
}

Setting the type to any or string works correctly, and inside the controller the authorId is an ObjectId.
@Get('books')
async getBooks(@Query('author_id', ParseObjectIdPipe) authorId: any){
   console.log(typeof authorId) // object
}


In main.ts, I have registered the ValidationPipe globally as follow:
app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
      forbidUnknownValues: true,
      whitelist: true,
      transform: true,
      stopAtFirstError: true,
      transformOptions: {
        ignoreDecorators: true
      }
    })
  )

